# My object is not changing direction after the collision (unity2D)

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
    Rigidbody2D _rb;
    float _speed = 5.0f;

    void Start()
    {
        _rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        _rb.velocity = new Vector2(_speed, 0f);
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "wall")
        {
            _rb.velocity = new Vector2(-_speed , 0f);   
        }
    }
}
```

i tried changing the velocity & tried using addforce, but still nothing changed.

Comment: `Update` is constantly setting `_rb.velocity` to be `_speed`. When your object collides it has velocity set to `-_speed` only for a brief moment before it is "reset" to `_speed` again.

Comment: Hint: if `_speed` controls the direction and it is re-applied every frame then in the collision method you don't have to change velocity (it will be insta restored anyway),  you need to change the value of `_speed` and `Update()` will apply it.

Comment: it works sir, thank you, but i had to include the physics2D material.